# loop to count nested JSON objects

Tags: python, json

I have a school assignment (intro to python so I am very much beginning my coding journey) I am looking for a more elegant way and not hardcoded way to solve the problem I was given.

**The problem**: I have a list of Nobel prizes winner and I need to count how many laureates there is in total for each category from a JSON file. So, I need to count nested JSON objects from nested arrays.

JSON link: http://api.nobelprize.org/v1/prize.json

JSON viewer: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

My code currently gives me the correct output, but it's hardcoded. Let's say that I have to re-do the assignment in X years and there's a new category of Nobel prizes, my program won't be able to catch it. I understand that I'll have to create a loop and that's where I am struggling... I am unsure how to create one from the set `category_count` since indexing is not possible in a set.

```
def nobel_data():   
    with open('prize.json', newline='') as jsonfile:
       nobel = json.load(jsonfile)
    
    category_count = set()

    for prize in nobel['prizes']:
      category_count.add(prize['category']) 

    dictio_cat = dict.fromkeys(category_count, 0)
  
  
    dictio_cat['chemistry'] = sum([len(item["laureates"]) for item in nobel["prizes"] if item["category"] == 'chemistry' and "laureates" in item])

    dictio_cat['economics'] = sum([len(item["laureates"]) for item in nobel["prizes"] if item["category"] == 'economics' and "laureates" in item])

    dictio_cat['peace'] = sum([len(item["laureates"]) for item in nobel["prizes"] if item["category"] == 'peace' and "laureates" in item])

    dictio_cat['physics'] = sum([len(item["laureates"]) for item in nobel["prizes"] if item["category"] == 'physics' and "laureates" in item])

    dictio_cat['literature'] = sum([len(item["laureates"]) for item in nobel["prizes"] if item["category"] == 'literature' and "laureates" in item])

    dictio_cat['medicine'] = sum([len(item["laureates"]) for item in nobel["prizes"] if item["category"] == 'medicine' and "laureates" in item])


    print(dictio_cat)
```

output

```
{'physics': 216, 'medicine': 222, 'economics': 86, 'peace': 135, 'chemistry': 186, 'literature': 117}
```

I am not looking for a complete solution, rather hints on how I can improve my code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: loop through the dictio_cat using: `for key, _ in dictio_cat.items()` and inside that assign value to `dictio_cat[key]`.

Comment: Another way is to just loop through `nobel["prizes"]` using: `for item in nobel["prizes"]` and inside that `dictio_cat[item["category"]] += len(item["laureates"])`

Comment: One way to improve the code is to indent it with four spaces, which is the defacto standard for Python. In any case, what other kinds of improvement do you have in mind?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I am looking to have a single loop that would assign the sum of laureate winners for each category as the value without looping each category individually. I'd like this part item["category"] == 'chemistry' to not be hard coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is use a `collections.defaultdict` and create a dictionary of all categories and keep adding up the total number of winners, if there were any.

For example:

```py
import collections

import requests

nobel_winners = requests.get("http://api.nobelprize.org/v1/prize.json").json()

total_laureates = collections.defaultdict(int)
for item in nobel_winners["prizes"]:
    if "laureates" in item.keys():
        total_laureates[item["category"]] += len(item["laureates"])

print(dict(total_laureates))
```

Output:

```
{'chemistry': 186, 'economics': 86, 'literature': 117, 'peace': 135, 'physics': 216, 'medicine': 222}
```